# Returning the Maximum of Date1 and Date2 in Cognos 10.2

Tags: business-intelligence, cognos, cognos-10

At my company we've recently moved from SSRS to a Cognos-based Reporting System, I don't have much experience with Cognos as a whole and am running into some issues that seem trivially easy to fix but I am struggling so far.

In our DB we segregate two kinds of contact date information [Date Emailed] and [Date Called], I'm attempting to combine both to get a [Date Contacted] field returned.

Is there a way for me in Cognos report builder to find the max of both of these data items?
I would have expected some kind of "c = MAX(a,b)" function like the below to be available but from what I've seen, apparently not.

> [Date Contacted] = MAX([Date Emailed], [Date Called])

Also, we have no access to modify SQL or any Cognos related part except the Report Builder which makes this all the more fun.

I feel like the answer will be building a CASE statement to do this, but I'd rather stay away from CASE if I can.

Thanks,
Blu

Comment: I don't believe you can do this without either a CASE statement of IF...THEN construct using Cognos functions. You can, however, try data source specific functions. When Cognos sees appropriate data source specific functions it passes them through where they are executed on the data source. Not knowing your data source, I can't give any more specific advice.

Comment: Thanks for that, just confirming my expectations so far.
The only reason I'm adverse to case/ IF..THEN statements is to do with run speed being dragged down when other parts of the query are running.
Looks like there's no way around it!

Comment: In my experience a simple CASE statement that chooses one column or another will not slow a report down appreciably. The majority of the processing time is in acuiring the raw data from the data source. The CASE solution happens after all of that has completed. If you want to be sure, you can install my Cognos performance measurement script which provides feedback as to the run time of your report, each time you run it.. Here's the link: http://cogblogger.com/2015/11/automated-cognos-report-performance-measurement/. Note the time before and after the change to see the impact.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you could use _days_between to determine which is the newer date.
Something like this:

Case 
(_days_between (X, Y) > 0 )

then (x)

// or Y; I can't remember whether the value returned is a negative or positive if the first parameter is greater than the second.  The expression editor's help will say.  Anyway, this is just to point you in a direction rather than me coming down from Mount Sinai.

case

(_days_between (X, Y) > 0 )

then

(x) // or Y;

Else (x or y but it doesn't matter as there's no difference )

Comment: He stated that he didn't want to use a CASE statement. If CASE statements weren't off the table then you could do simply `CASE WHEN X >= Y THEN X ELSE Y END`. There would be no need to count the days between,